# Python Module Not Found Error: First function found, but second is not

Tags: python, python-module

I have a simple dir structure:

```
project/
  __init__.py
  main.py
  dir1/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  dir2/
  dir3/
```

Inside of main.py:

```
from dir1.foo import function1, function2
```

function1 is imported, but function2 is not, and the following error is thrown.

> No module named dir1.foo found.

I have no idea how this is possible.

Edit: I am able to use function1 in main(), but when function2 is called the error is thrown.

Comment: If you print `function1.__module__`, what does it say?

Comment: what makes you think that function1 is imported?

Comment: @zondo function1.__module__ prints dir1.foo

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am able to use function1 (also function1.__module__ prints appropriate module)

Comment: Can you show the code that throws the error?  Also, please include the full traceback.

Comment: @VeryBamboozled Since you say that you can use the function1, I am assuming that it has executed past this statement in main.py:- `from dir1.foo import function1, function2`. That itself indicates there are no errors in imports. Try including the code for providing more information.